# Javascript Calendar Drop Down

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a virtual javascript calendar drop down.  I want the correct number of days to be displayed when a  month is selected, but anytime I select something NO days are displayed.  Please help.  I CANT use jquery again or theyll fire me this time.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(x) {
var mon = document.getElementById(x).innerHTML;
//if month value is nothing display no days
if (mon == "") {
    document.getElementById("one").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("two").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("three").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("four").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("five").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("six").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("seven").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("eight").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("nine").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("ten").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("eleven").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("twelve").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("thirteen").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("fourteen").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("fifteen").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("sixteen").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("seventeen").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("eighteen").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("nineteen").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("twenty").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("twentyone").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("twentytwo").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("twentythree").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("twentyfour").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("twentyfive").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("twentysix").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("twentyseven").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("twentyeight").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("twentynine").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("thirty").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("thirtyone").style.display="none";
//if month value has 31 days then display all 31 days
} else if ((mon == "January") || (mon == "March") || (mon == "May") || (mon == "July") || (mon == "August") || (mon == "October") || (mon == "December")) {
    document.getElementById("one").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("two").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("three").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("four").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("five").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("six").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("seven").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("eight").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("nine").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("ten").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("eleven").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twelve").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("thirteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("fourteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("fifteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("sixteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("seventeen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("eighteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("nineteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twenty").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyone").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentytwo").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentythree").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyfour").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyfive").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentysix").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyseven").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyeight").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentynine").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("thirty").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("thirtyone").style.display="";
//if month value has 30 days then display 30 days
} else if ((mon == "April") || (mon == "June") || (mon == "September") || (mon == "November")) {
    document.getElementById("one").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("two").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("three").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("four").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("five").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("six").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("seven").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("eight").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("nine").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("ten").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("eleven").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twelve").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("thirteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("fourteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("fifteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("sixteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("seventeen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("eighteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("nineteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twenty").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyone").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentytwo").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentythree").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyfour").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyfive").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentysix").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyseven").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyeight").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentynine").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("thirty").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("thirtyone").style.display="none";

//case if month value is Feb
} else {
    document.getElementById("one").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("two").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("three").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("four").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("five").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("six").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("seven").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("eight").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("nine").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("ten").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("eleven").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twelve").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("thirteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("fourteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("fifteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("sixteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("seventeen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("eighteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("nineteen").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twenty").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyone").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentytwo").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentythree").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyfour").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyfive").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentysix").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyseven").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentyeight").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("twentynine").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("thirty").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("thirtyone").style.display="none";
    //check to see if it was a leap year
    if (/*check if year is divisible by four and has a remainder of zero)*/ {
        //document.getElementById("twentynine").style.display="";
    } else {
    }
}
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
Calendar<br>
<hr align="left" width="200px"/>


--Year ------ Month ----- Day<br>

<select name="year">
<option value="defaulty"></option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>

<select name="month" onchange="show(this.value)">
<option id="defaultm" value="defaultm"></option>
<option id="January" value="January">January</option>
<option id="February" value="February">February</option>
<option id="March" value="March">March</option>
<option id="April" value="April">April</option>
<option id="May" value="May">May</option>
<option id="June" value="June">June</option>
<option id="July" value="July">July</option>
<option id="August" value="August">August</option>
<option id="September" value="September">September</option>
<option id="October" value="October">October</option>
<option id="November" value="November">November</option>
<option id="December" value="December">December</option>
</select>

<select name="day">
<option id="defaultd" value="defaultd"></option>
<option id="one" value="one" style="display:none">1</option>
<option id="two" value="two" style="display:none">2</option>
<option id="three" value="three" style="display:none">3</option>
<option id="four" value="four" style="display:none">4</option>
<option id="five" value="five" style="display:none">5</option>
<option id="six" value="six" style="display:none">6</option>
<option id="seven" value="seven" style="display:none">7</option>
<option id="eight" value="eight" style="display:none">8</option>
<option id="nine" value="nine" style="display:none">9</option>
<option id="ten" value="ten" style="display:none">10</option>
<option id="eleven" value="eleven" style="display:none">11</option>
<option id="twelve" value="twelve" style="display:none">12</option>
<option id="thirteen" value="thirteen" style="display:none">13</option>
<option id="fourteen" value="fourteen" style="display:none">14</option>
<option id="fifteen" value="fifteen" style="display:none">15</option>
<option id="sixteen" value="sixteen" style="display:none">16</option>
<option id="seventeen" value="seventeen" style="display:none">17</option>
<option id="eighteen" value="eighteen" style="display:none">18</option>
<option id="nineteen" value="nineteen" style="display:none">19</option>
<option id="twenty" value="twenty" style="display:none">20</option>
<option id="twentyone" value="twentyone" style="display:none">21</option>
<option id="twentytwo" value="twentytwo" style="display:none">22</option>
<option id="twentythree" value="twentythree" style="display:none">23</option>
<option id="twentyfour" value="twentyfour" style="display:none">24</option>
<option id="twentyfive" value="twentyfive" style="display:none">25</option>
<option id="twentysix" value="twentysix" style="display:none">26</option>
<option id="twentyseven" value="twentyseven" style="display:none">27</option>
<option id="twentyeight" value="twentyeight" style="display:none">28</option>
<option id="twentynine" value="twentynine" style="display:none">29</option>
<option id="thirty" value="thirty" style="display:none">30</option>
<option id="thirtyone" value="thirtyone" style="display:none">31</option>

</select>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh...... You can use the `getElementsByTagName.`

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel  when awesome plugins are there to do this ? Think about the user also.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? There are so many scripts, libraries and plugins to do this for you.

Comment: i do not know of them.. and also i cant use jquery again or they said theyll fire me..

Comment: ditto. Also, all months have 28 days so why repeat all that code

Comment: I suggest you check `jQuery UI DatePicker`'s code and try to work your own

Comment: can you guys please just help me with what I have??

Comment: @StackOver: If you do not want an answer with jQuery, please do not use jQuery tag when creating the question.

Comment: check your leapyear calc too http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year Also Pre-jQueryUI I used a date-picker (just google one) then moved to a dhtmlx calendar

Comment: I cant use Jqyuery and I dont want to use a date picker calendar..I have to do it this way..please help with what I have

Comment: also you will have to change display on year change too as Leap Year changes Feb. You dont have to use the datepicker but it will show you some nice Js code to pinch for yours :)

Comment: If I ever saw someone using such WET code, I'd quit my job instantly. Not offensively, just sayin'.

Comment: You should have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex7/jasoncalendar.htm hope it helps :)

Comment: Stackoverflow.com is not a website where we give you the code. Sorry, we're not there to **do your job**.

Comment: because I need help fixing the code I HAVE

Comment: My only advice would be to completely rewrite the code. First, you don't have to run 30+ times the same operation with `getElementById`, give them a common class and work with it instead. Secondly, the `option` element's display doesn't apply properly on IE. And as @FlorianMargaine said, if you don't put any effort in solving your extremely-localized issue and simply dump your dripping-WET code to abominate our poor answerers then it's not a good fit for SO.

Comment: All right, this needs to stop. Now. Keep the conversation constructive, or end it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well to add some actual content to this comment discussion: Here is your jQuery free PURE JS solution.

I chose to do it this way because 1) I hate writing HTML, and 2) to show you the power of learning Javascript properly.

There are some browser compatibility issues with my code (namely older IE versions) I will let you figure these out and handle them on your own.

html:

```
<div id="calendar-container"></div>
```

js:

```
(function() {
    var calendar = [
        ["January", 31],
        ["February", 28],
        ["March", 31],
        ["April", 30],
        ["May", 31],
        ["June", 30],
        ["July", 31],
        ["August", 31],
        ["September", 30],
        ["October", 31],
        ["November", 30],
        ["December", 31]
        ],
        cont = document.getElementById('calendar-container');

    var sel_year = document.createElement('select'),
        sel_month = document.createElement('select'),
        sel_day = document.createElement('select');

    function createOption(txt, val) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = val;
        option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
        return option;
    }

    function clearChildren(ele) {
        while (ele.hasChildNodes()) {
            ele.removeChild(ele.lastChild);
        }
    }

    function recalculateDays() {
        var month_index = sel_month.value,
            df = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var i = 0, l = calendar[month_index][1]; i < l; i++) {
            df.appendChild(createOption(i + 1, i));
        }
        clearChildren(sel_day);
        sel_day.appendChild(df);
    }

    function generateMonths() {
        var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
        calendar.forEach(function(info, i) {
            df.appendChild(createOption(info[0], i));
        });
        clearChildren(sel_month);
        sel_month.appendChild(df);
    }

    sel_month.onchange = recalculateDays;

    generateMonths();
    recalculateDays();

    cont.appendChild(sel_year);
    cont.appendChild(sel_month);
    cont.appendChild(sel_day);
}());​
```

And here is your [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/j2kzv/)

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I wish you could have kept it similar to my code, but Im not going to complain with the previous commenters' "help"

Comment: I took it drastically away from your previous code because you were approaching it wrong. There are many ways to go about this, and many improvements to be made on this code too (like using the date object to calculate stuff for feb + leap years.) - however I have tried to keep the idea that dates were hard coded and not calculated.

Comment: Also, I tried to make everything as transparent, verbose, and readable for your benefit :)

Comment: @Waygood had to leave something for the OP. also, My job is not at risk, so I can afford to be lazy